# Python nondeterministic epsilon authomaton : object is not iterable

Tags: python, runtime-error, computation-theory, automaton

I have to make non-deterministic finite automaton with epsilon transitions. I'm more of a c, c#, JavaScript guy, but my university thinks python is the only way to go for some reason, so today I learned python, but obviously not enough.

Anyway. Problem is in "`automaton`" function. I call it with initial state list with one element (`stanje1`) and array of characters that automaton has to read (`inputArrays[0]`) along with dictionary that defines transition function (dictionary key is string `currentState,inputCharacter` and value is array of next states).

First iteration runs fine, but when I want to recursively check all states I got via epsilon transition against next character I get error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Automaton recursion is called with all arguments defined similarely as in top call, yet error somehow just jumps out.

Here's [link to my code](http://pastebin.com/5zTixvMS), as well as test file that [defines automaton](http://pastebin.com/aqdRymv9) (you need to run it like so `myScript.py < automaton.txt`). Also, here's a full error report:

```
C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\UTRLabos1>sim.py < test.txt
['stanje1']
['st6']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\UTRLabos1\sim.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(automaton(['stanje1'], inputArrays[0], transitionFunction))
File "C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\UTRLabos1\sim.py", line 45, in automaton
    if estates : other = automaton(estates, ir[1:], fn)
File "C:\Users\Jinx\Desktop\UTRLabos1\sim.py", line 37, in automaton
    states += eNKA(s, ir[0], fn)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hint is that the crash occurs on this line:

```
states += eNKA(s, ir[0], fn)
```

and not deeper inside the `eNKA` function. You may suspect that something on this line is `None`, instead of an iterable. `ir` can't possibly be `None` because you checked for that possibility earlier, so it must be the case that the return value of `eNKA` is `None` (and you are effectively doing `states += None`).

In fact, this is the case. `eNKA` doesn't `return` a value in every possible case, which may result in the default value of `None` to be returned.

Thus, the fix would be to see why every `if` condition in `eNKA` is failing, and fix that appropriately (or return something more sensible if every condition fails).

Comment: Are you sure? It is about an iterable, which has nothing to do with addition. It would rather be `ir` being `None`.

Comment: It worked. Though I really don't see why would that affect my code in such a way. I'm not iterating through values of eNKA. Thanks!

Comment: `states` is a list.  `somelist += x` has to iterate over `x` in order to extend the list.  (Whether that's what you want to do I'm not sure, but that's how iteration is involved.)